# Endlessly moving through an array backwards

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I've got to be able moving through an array forwards and backwards. Endlessly and without getting an index out of bounds-exception.

For moving forward I've known an elegant way using the modulo-operator. For the backwards moving I've had to figure out something myself.

Here's my solution:

```js
const inc = document.getElementById("inc");
const dec = document.getElementById("dec");
const arr = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"];
let i = 0;

inc.addEventListener("click", () => {
  i = (i + 1) % arr.length;

  console.log(arr[i]);
});

dec.addEventListener("click", () => {
  i = i - 1;

  if (i === -1) {
    i = arr.length - 1;
  }

  console.log(arr[i]);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="inc">Inc</button>
  <button id="dec">Dec</button>
</body>

</html>
```

It works. **But is there a more elegant solution for moving backwards?**

So that one can get rid of this ugly if-check.

Comment: A related topic are the [differences of modulo in programming and math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Variants_of_the_definition). In math, `-1 mod 5 ≡ 4`, while in most programming languages (thanks IEEE754, though probably having its reasons), `-1 % 5 === -1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you could use a *single* formula for both `forwards` and `backwards` by creating a common function `move` and pass the `step` as parameter.

> i = (i + step + arr.length ) % arr.length;

```js
let arr = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"] , i = 0
function move(step){
  i = (i + step + arr.length ) % arr.length;
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

```html
<button id="inc" onclick="move(1)">Inc</button>
<button id="dec" onclick="move(-1)">Dec</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can still use the modulus operator. To go backwards, it'd be

```
i = (i - 1 + array.length) % array.length;
```

When `i` is 0, the partial result will be `(0 - 1 + array.length)`, which is `array.length - 1`.

For any value greater than 0 but less than `array.length`, the modulus operator maps the value greater than `array.length` to the correct index in range.